# I need to format data in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to format a large set of data across multiple columns.
I have data in sets of 2 columns that need to be formatted into one set of 2 columns, in addition to headers that need to be in cells to the left of the data.

So I need to covert data that is in two columns to:

header1 header2 data1 data2

So the header needs to be copied and pasted all the way down the columns and the multiple columns and headers need to be appended.

This needs to loop across a whole spreadsheet.

[image]

Below is my attempt

```
colA = 5
colB = 3
colC = 2
rowA = 3
rowB = 3
cellA = "C1"
Worksheets("sheet3").Activate
lastA = Cells(Rows.Count, colB).End(xlUp).Row
For x = rowA To lastA
    Worksheets("sheet3").Activate
    Data = Cells(x, colA)
    Worksheets("sheet3").Activate
    Cells(rowB, colB) = Data
    rowB = rowB + 1
Next x
Do Until colC = 0
Selection.Cut
Cells(1, colB).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("D1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Cells(3, colC)
colC = colB - 1
```

Comment: I think I am lost. Could you post a before and after screenshot of what are you trying to do. You may not be able to upload the image in the question above so simple upload the image in a free file sharing site and share the link here.

Comment: Hi,
yes, the image is here http://imgur.com/qHgIxvv. I'd like to format the data on the left to look like the right. I have multiple columns that look like the data on the left that need to be converted to 4 columns so I think it needs to loop until it finishes. Thank you!!

Comment: I am still confused. There are 19 `data5` in the source table but only 7 `data5` in the destination table. How did that happen?

Comment: Sorry I rushed while creating the image so it is not exact. There should be the same number of cells on both sides, so there should be 19 data5 in the destination table.

Comment: Can you please take your time to create the sample? This will ensure that you don't waste our time as well as your time :)

Comment: Sure, sorry about that! Is this more clear? http://imgur.com/WW6kRPs I have tens of columns in pairs of 2, formatted in the way on the left and they need to be converted to the format on the right. So I think I'll just need a loop to go across the worksheet.

Comment: Hi, Did that help at all? Even a simple copy and paste range loop would help. I can't seem to find anything close for my purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Different approach.

Read the source data into an array.
Set up a Class consisting of the data for each resultant row
Iterate through the source array, two columns at a time, to construct each row.
Store the RowData into a collection.
When done, transfer the collection into a "results" array.
Write the results array to a Range (I chose to do do this on a different worksheet).  Edit the source and destination ranges as required.

First Insert a Class Module; Rename it  **RowData**, and paste the code below:

```
Option Explicit
Private pHeaderOdd As String
Private pHeaderEven As String
Private pDataOdd As String
Private pDataEven As String

Public Property Get HeaderOdd() As String
    HeaderOdd = pHeaderOdd
End Property
Public Property Let HeaderOdd(Value As String)
    pHeaderOdd = Value
End Property

Public Property Get HeaderEven() As String
    HeaderEven = pHeaderEven
End Property
Public Property Let HeaderEven(Value As String)
    pHeaderEven = Value
End Property

Public Property Get DataOdd() As String
    DataOdd = pDataOdd
End Property
Public Property Let DataOdd(Value As String)
    pDataOdd = Value
End Property

Public Property Get DataEven() As String
    DataEven = pDataEven
End Property
Public Property Let DataEven(Value As String)
    pDataEven = Value
End Property
```

Then, in a regular module, paste the following code:

```
Sub ReFormat()
    Dim V As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim cRD As RowData
    Dim colRD As Collection

    Dim I As Long, J As Long

'Get entire source data into array
'May need a different selection method
'  depending on your "real" data arrangement

V = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("a1").CurrentRegion

'initialize collection
Set colRD = New Collection

'get data in pairs and add to collection
For I = 1 To UBound(V, 2) Step 2 'columns
    For J = 2 To UBound(V, 1) 'rows
        Set cRD = New RowData
            cRD.HeaderOdd = V(1, I)
            cRD.HeaderEven = V(1, I + 1)
            cRD.DataOdd = V(J, I)
            cRD.DataEven = V(J, I + 1)
        colRD.Add cRD
    Next J
Next I

'Put collection into "results" array for writing to the results range    
ReDim vRes(1 To colRD.Count, 1 To 4)
For I = 1 To colRD.Count
    vRes(I, 1) = colRD(I).HeaderOdd
    vRes(I, 2) = colRD(I).HeaderEven
    vRes(I, 3) = colRD(I).DataOdd
    vRes(I, 4) = colRD(I).DataEven
Next I

Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells.Clear
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2)) = vRes

End Sub
```

Ensure your worksheet and range references are correct, and run the macro.